# Can this SQL MERGE table copy be written as a single operation?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

Using the DB2 for i platform, I have been successfully using two operations to do a whole-table data update from one table to another:

```
-- put values from source file into target file
MERGE INTO TLIB.TABLE AS T USING SLIB.TABLE AS S
  ON (T.KEY1 = S.KEY1 AND T.KEY2  = S.KEY2)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT VALUES(S.KEY1, S.KEY2, S.FIELD1, S.FIELD1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET ROW = (S.KEY1, S.KEY2, S.FIELD1, S.FIELD1);

-- remove records that are in target file but not source file
DELETE FROM TLIB.TABLE T2
WHERE RRN(T2) IN (
  SELECT RRN(T)
  FROM TLIB.TABLE AS T
  LEFT JOIN SLIB.TABLE AS S
    ON (T.KEY1 = S.KEY1 AND T.KEY2 = S.KEY2)
  WHERE S.KEY1 IS NULL);
```

This has been giving me the result I want, but I can't help think that there is a way to make this into one statement, maybe some kind of join on the source table inside of the merge statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a full join of the source and target tables before you merge, you can then tell which records exist in one, the other, or both and adjust your merge actions accordingly:

```
MERGE INTO TLIB.TABLE AS T USING (
  SELECT S1.*, T1.KEY1 AS TKEY1, T1.KEY2 AS TKEY2
  FROM SLIB.TABLE AS S1
  FULL OUTER JOIN TLIB.TABLE AS T1
    ON T1.KEY1 = S1.KEY1 AND T1.KEY2 = S1.KEY2
  ) AS S ON COALESCE(S.KEY1, TKEY1) = T.KEY1 AND
            COALESCE(S.KEY2, TKEY2) = T.KEY1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT VALUES(S.KEY1, S.KEY2, S.FIELD1, S.FIELD1)
WHEN MATCHED AND S.KEY1 IS NULL THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED AND S.KEY1 IS NOT NULL THEN 
  UPDATE SET ROW = (S.KEY1, S.KEY2, S.FIELD1, S.FIELD1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a union of rows from `SLIB` and rows from `TLIB that are not in SLIB` with a provenance column and test that provenance column when matched

```
MERGE INTO TLIB.TABLE AS T USING (
  select 'SLIB' PROVENANCE, sl.* from SLIB.TABLE sl
  union all select 'TLIB' PROVENANCE, tl.* from TLIB.TABLE TL left join SLIB.TABLE SL on (sl.key1, sl.key2) = (tl.key1, tl.key2) where sl.key1 is null
  ) AS S
  ON (T.KEY1 = S.KEY1 AND T.KEY2  = S.KEY2)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT VALUES(S.KEY1, S.KEY2, S.FIELD1, S.FIELD1)
WHEN MATCHED and PROVENANCE = 'SLIB' THEN
  UPDATE SET ROW = (S.KEY1, S.KEY2, S.FIELD1, S.FIELD1)
WHEN MATCHED and PROVENANCE = 'TLIB' THEN
  DELETE;
```

Comment: It would if the second table in the union did an exception join instead of an outer join.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy the where condition makes it an equivalent of an exception join. I never use exception join because AFAIK only DB2 for i accepts it

Comment: Ok, I missed that simply because you were recreating a feature built in to the database. If you are working with DB2, then why not use the features provided. Every database has some features that do not exist in others. MS SQL Server has a lot of features that are not ANSI standard compliant. Not sure if it's true in this case, but when you roll your own, you could easily confuse the optimizer and not get the performance you expect.